# Overriding settings.py email settings in view

Tags: django

The email settings that are used by a post request need to depend on logic within my view. As a result, I'd like to overwrite the following email settings within my view, which are typically set in settings.py:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@website.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****************'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'user@website.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'user@website.com'
```

Based on my reading (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module), I believe the best way to do this is as follows:

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

def myview(request):

    profile = ..logic that grab's user's profile...

    settings.configure(EMAIL_HOST_USER = profile.email)
    settings.configure(EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = profile.email_password)
    settings.configure(DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = profile.email)
    settings.configure(SERVER_EMAIL = profile.email)
```

Can you confirm that this is the most appropriate way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should work, but it's not recommended to [alter settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

You can pass all these values when calling [send_mail()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail) so there is no need to modify settings. Just pass proper keyword arguments when sending the email.

You can also use the [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) class to have more control.

You can create an object of EmailMessage like this:

```
# from Django docs
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
    ['bcc@example.com'],
    reply_to=['another@example.com'],
    headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
)

email.send()
```

See attached links to docs for more info.

Comment: The key parameter for this case is the 'connection' that you did not mention.